# Variadic Macros : how to solve "too many actual parameters for macro.."

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, macros, variadic-functions

Ive been working on getting some of my code originally built on the mac to run under Visual Studio 2008 Express and have run into a weird problem with the variadic macros i use for my assert code :

The macro is defined as :

```
#define SH_ASSERT( assertID, exp, description, ... ) shAssertBasic( int(exp), assertID, description, __LINE__, __FILE__ , ##__VA_ARGS__ )
```

This all works fine under gcc (under osx) and used to run under VS 2005 however with 2008 I get the following warning :

```
 warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'SH_ASSERT'
```

The calling code is simply :

```
SH_ASSERT(0, donkeys != aliens , "Donkeys are Aliens Code : Code %d condition %d" , 55, 666);
```

I'm sure Im missing something simple and my google foo is failing me...

Thanks.

Comment: I confirm it successfully builds and runs "as-is" with VS2005, even with `/W1`. All I can say is make sure `SH_ASSERT` is not (re)defined somewhere else as non-variadic (I doubt you changed that though).  You probably can't just disable the warning, as the preprocessor will throw away what it thinks is excess.

Comment: The macro isnt getting redefined, I double checked that one. It must be something specific to the 2005 -> 2008 differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the argument order (put description with the ... part) to do something like this:

```
#define SH_ASSERT( assertID, exp, ... ) shAssertBasic( int(exp), assertID, __LINE__, __FILE__, __VA_ARGS__ )
```

It should do the trick, You also have the possibility to suppress the warning in windows:

```
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning( disable:code/number )
#pragma warning (pop)
```